# UITabBarItem loses tint on PopViewController

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, popviewcontrolleranimated

Ok, so, I have UINavigationController embedded in a UITabBarController. When selecting the tab bar item, I am presented with the UITableView that is the root of the NavController. Selecting an item in the table takes me to the next view (push) where I set values for that item. Upon hitting Save Changes, I pop the user back to the root controller (the table view). However, the UITabBarItem has gone from a tint of Blue back to the default tint of grey. If, while in the second screen, I hit cancel in the NavBar to return to the root, the UITabBarItem is fine, i.e. still selected and tinted blue.

I have tried several approaches including setting the TabBar's selected item on viewWillAppear as well as trying to set the tint in the UITabBarController itself. Nothing seems to fix the issue. What is really interesting is that, in the UITableView's viewDidAppear (the root view) if I set the selected TabBarItem's tint to blue, the resulting color is a dark grey.

If I select another item in the tab bar and then select the first item again, the blue tint returns. It has something to do with the popping back to the root view that is causing this.

Has anyone seen this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any modals or pop-ups (such as an AlertView) in either viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad, (or anytime before the view has finally appeared), it will cause the tint to change upon popping a view.

Check your second view controller if it has any such thing.